# Modifying state through both parent and child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What's the best practice in React for allowing both a component and a parent component to modify the same state?

[Example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-nightingale-sbcfj?file=/src/App.js)

Basically, I want each individual ColorDisplay component to be able to change their own displayed color, which is what the Change Color button does. But I also want to be able to set the displayed color of all the components to match one component. This is what the Change All Colors To This Color button is supposed to do, but doesn't right now because I'm not sure what the correct method of doing it is. Right now it just sets a universal color.

All the methods I've thought of for solving this so far involve a universalColor in the parent which is then passed to the children. Each child then renders either the universalColor or their own individualColor according to some logic. However, all the logic paths I can think of break on this set of conditions:

The user sets all displays to match color display A.

The user then changes the color on color display B.

The user then sets all displays to match color display A again.

Just checking if props has changed doesn't worked in this case because A's color hasn't changed. But always rendering the prop value doesn't work either because when the user changes the individual color, I want that change reflected, but just on the one ColorDisplay where it was changed.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of doing that would be controlling the colors with a single state and each display only being able to change it's own key in the state, while the parent can control all keys.

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState({
   displayA: 'red',
   displayB: 'blue'
})

const handleColor = (displayKey, newColor) => {
  const updatedColors = {...colors};
  updatedColors[displayKey] = newColor;
  setColors(updatedColors);
}

return (
<> 
  <DisplayA 
    color={colors['displayA']} 
    changeColor={(newColor) => handleColor('displayA', newColor)}
  />
  <DisplayB 
    color={colors['displayB']} 
    changeColor={() => handleColor('displayB')}
  />
</>
)
```

In the example above each display only changes its own key in the state. You could also add a new function that handles a change for all of them.